# Selenium webdriver code takes time to exit while loop

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The code I have works but when the while loop breaks, it takes like 20 seconds for what's below the while loop to execute.

Here is the code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    try {
        driver.get("website");
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {

        String x = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b")).getText();



        driver.get("website");
        driver.findElement(By.id("479510558845313")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamusernameinput);        driver.findElement(By.id("263795143794707")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamcommentinput);

        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_4")).sendKeys(x);
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
        while (true){
            WebElement button = null;
            try {
              button = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[action='cancel']"));
            } catch (NoSuchElementException ex){
              break; 
            }
            if (button.isDisplayed() == false) {
              break;
            }

            driver.navigate().refresh();

            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
            driver.findElement(By.id("479510558845313")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamusernameinput);

            driver.findElement(By.id("263795143794707")).sendKeys(InstagramAievx.spamcommentinput);

            driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_4")).sendKeys(x);
            driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_5")).click();
        }

        killFirefox();
    }
```

Any idea of what's causing this ~20 second delay.

Comment: How did you define the implicit wait? `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait()`

Comment: @Guy Thanks for your reply. Yeah I found out that this was the problem. It was at 30s then I changed it to 10s. Now everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Decreasing the implicit wait timeout duration is not a good solution. The problem in your code is that your `findElement()` waits for whatever implicit wait duration you set, which is useless if the element is not there, so this is not a good solution either.

If you expect an element to be not present (or even possibly not present), it's sometimes a good idea to temporarily disable the implicit wait.

In this case, you already do some `findElement()` calls before the `while` loop even starts, so there's no more need for implicit wait at this point, because you can be sure that the document has already been loaded. So you could set the implicit wait to 0 seconds before the `while` loop and back to 30 seconds afterwards and you're fine.